# Proof by induction for certain ceiling\floor?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-explanation

Determine whether each of these proposed definitions is
a valid recursive definition of a function
from the set $f$ of nonnegative integers to the set of integers. If $f$ is well
defined, find a formula for $f(n)$ when $n$ is a nonnegative
integer and prove that your formula is valid.

$a) f(0) = 1, f(1)=0, f(2)=2, f(n)=2f(n-3)$ for $n\geq3$

$b) f(0) = 2, f(n)=f(n-1)$ if $n$ is odd and $n \geq 1$ and $f(n) = 2f(n-2)$ if $n \geq 2$

I'm having trouble with these two mostly because they might involve a floor or a ceiling function and I have no idea how to do induction on that. any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Why would these involve the floor or ceiling functions?  The only objects you are working with are integers, which are unchanged by these functions...

Comment: What Xander said. Plus, here is a couple of hints when you have no idea what to do: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27923/how-to-prevent-no-clue-questions

Comment: Start with problem (a). Make a table n | f(n). Fill the table in for n = 0 up to n = 14. Conjecture a pattern (a pattern may become blatantly obvious before you even hit n = 14, but maybe not). Try to prove that your conjecture is true via a common way to prove something is true for every natural number.

Comment: The reason why I mention floor/ceiling is because that's all I've seen when I look up these parts. it makes sense but proving it by induction is tricky.

Comment: Proving what? You don't even have the thing to prove yet. The problem asks you to find the thing that needs proving. This is one of the most fun type of problems because you get to explore!

Comment: "The reason why I mention floor/ceiling is because that's all I've seen when I look up these parts."  That makes about as much sense as "purple monkey dishwasher".  Look up what parts?  Look them up where?  This has nothing to do with floor and ceiling functions.

Comment: @JorgeSepúlveda I am hesitating to post an answer to this question because I think exploring and finding the pattern in (a) is an important thing for a young math student to do. Likely, someone will answer soon though. You should really at least try to conjecture the formula for f(n) on your own and then maybe turn to the group for help proving said formula. Do you know what it means for numbers to be congruent? It isn't necessary to solve the problem but would make the argument more obvious to present.

Comment: The hint that Salahamam gave was pretty helpful. I was making the pattern but didn't quite see that the formula acted differently when n is a multiple of 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**hint for the first**

for $k\ge 0$,

$$f (3k)=2f (3 (k-1))=2^kf (0)=2^k $$

$$f (3k+1)=2f (3 (k-1)+1)=2^kf (1)=0$$

$$f (3k+2)=2f (3 (k-1)+2)=2^kf (2)=2^{k+1} $$